# conversejs + openfire + smack prebind issue

Tags: openfire, smack, converse.js

I'm using smack to build the bosh connection to openfire. 
I modified the BOSHConnection file to get sid and rid.
But when use it connect to conversejs, after few second it auto logout.
My conversejs setting something like:

```
keepalive: true,
authentication: 'prebind',
jid: 'xxxx@xxxx',
sid: '44sa2vqziv',
rid: '6053815847634846',
prebind: true,
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, just need to close the connection